# What is this shape?

Tags: shapes, terminology

[image]

I want to create a shape like this in MS Office. But in order to find out how to do that, I need to know the name of the shape. Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a specific name for this, and no idea about MS Office, but in Adobe Illustrator there is a Warp tool and with the Inflate style at about 15% bend setting, you get this, starting from a normal rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me a lot of tube/CRT television screens. There's probably not a particular name for this shape. You could describe it as a rounded rectangle with the edges slightly protruding outward.